# SystemJS errors after upgrading from Angular 2 to Angular 4

Tags: systemjs, angular

I upgraded from angular 2.3.1 to 4.0.1. I now get a SystemJS error when my page fails to load in the dev tools console:

```
(SystemJS) exports is not defined
    ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

I understand that the modules are being packaged differently but I assume the older versions are still being supported:

> Flat ES Modules (Flat ESM / FESM)
>   We now ship flattened versions of our modules ("rolled up" version of our code in the EcmaScript Module format, see example file). This format should help tree-shaking, help reduce the size of your generated bundles, and speed up build, transpilation, and loading in the browser in certain scenarios.
>
> Read more about the importance of Flat ES Modules in "The cost of small modules".
>   Experimental ES2015 Builds
>   We now also ship our packages in the ES2015 Flat ESM format. This option is experimental and opt-in. Developers have reported up to 7% bundle size savings when combining these packages with Rollup. To try out these new packages, configure your build toolchain to resolve "es2015" property in package.json over the regular "module" property.

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Comment: update your post with more information